# More efficient way of converting Keycode Alphas to integers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, keyboard

In C#, specificially in a Unity Script, I can use the following line to know if a key (here, the number 1 on the keyboard, non-keypad) has been pressed in the last frame.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
{
    MethodCall(1)
}
```

Now in my game, I'd like the call the exact same method no matter which number is pressed, but use that number as a parameter, and I'd like all the numbers to work. So of course I could do this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
{
    MethodCall(1)
}
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2))
{
    MethodCall(2)
}
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha3))
{
    MethodCall(3)
}
// Etc
```

But This seems like a terribly inefficient way of processing this specific use case.

I've thought about simply converting the key pressed into it's own char, then into a string, then parsing it as an int, but I still have to do a huge if to check if the key was at least one of the numbers.

So what's the most efficient way, in code-length and in execution time if the answer wouldn't be the same, to do this specific task?

Comment: I would create a method `int GetKeyPressed (..)` which will return me 1,2 or 3 or N. Inside you can have a long set of `switch..case` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Dictionary with [`Keycode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html) as the the key and the function(`Action`) as the value. Add the function with the respective parameter in the `Start` function. This will get ride of all the `if` or `switch` statement.

```
Dictionary<KeyCode, System.Action> keyCodeDic = new Dictionary<KeyCode, System.Action>();
```

---

The Alpha `Keycode` enum starts at `48` and ends at `57`.

```
Alpha0 = 48,
Alpha1 = 49,
Alpha2 = 50,
Alpha3 = 51,
Alpha4 = 52,
Alpha5 = 53,
Alpha6 = 54,
Alpha7 = 55,
Alpha8 = 56,
Alpha9 = 57,
```

In the `Start` function, loop from `48` to `57` then cast each `int` value from the loop to [`Keycode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html). Add the `keycode` to the `Dictionary` in each loop. Also, have a temporary variable you will use as the function parameter. This variable should start from `0` and be incremented after each loop. It should start from 0 because the Alpha keys on the keyboard starts from `0` (Alpha0):

```
int paramValue = 0;
for (int i = 48; i <= 57; i++)
{
    KeyCode tempKeyCode = (KeyCode)i;

    //Use temp variable to prevent it from being capture
    int temParam = paramValue;
    keyCodeDic.Add(tempKeyCode, () => MethodCall(temParam));
    paramValue++;
}
```

Finally, in the `Update` function loop through the `Dictionary` and check if the key from is pressed then call the corresponding function which is the value from that key in the `Dictionary`.

```
//Loop through the Dictionary and check if the Registered Keycode is pressed
foreach (KeyValuePair<KeyCode, System.Action> entry in keyCodeDic)
{
    //Check if the keycode is pressed
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(entry.Key))
    {
        //Check if the key pressed exist in the dictionary key
        if (keyCodeDic.ContainsKey(entry.Key))
        {
            //Debug.Log("Pressed" + entry.Key);

            //Call the function stored in the Dictionary's value
            keyCodeDic[entry.Key].Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is what the whole thing should look like:

```
Dictionary<KeyCode, System.Action> keyCodeDic = new Dictionary<KeyCode, System.Action>();

void Start()
{
    //Register Keycodes to to match each function to call
    const int alphaStart = 48;
    const int alphaEnd = 57;

    int paramValue = 0;
    for (int i = alphaStart; i <= alphaEnd; i++)
    {
        KeyCode tempKeyCode = (KeyCode)i;

        //Use temp variable to prevent it from being capture
        int temParam = paramValue;
        keyCodeDic.Add(tempKeyCode, () => MethodCall(temParam));
        paramValue++;
    }
}

void MethodCall(int keyNum)
{
    Debug.Log("Pressed: " + keyNum);
}


void Update()
{
    //Loop through the Dictionary and check if the Registered Keycode is pressed
    foreach (KeyValuePair<KeyCode, System.Action> entry in keyCodeDic)
    {
        //Check if the keycode is pressed
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(entry.Key))
        {
            //Check if the key pressed exist in the dictionary key
            if (keyCodeDic.ContainsKey(entry.Key))
            {
                //Debug.Log("Pressed" + entry.Key);

                //Call the function stored in the Dictionary's value
                keyCodeDic[entry.Key].Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems pretty clean, works fine and I don't see any performance loss compared to my ugly method. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just as a quick improvement, it has been said TryGetValue to be faster than Contains. To be confirmed.

Comment: That's right. I left the `keyCodeDic.ContainsKey` on purpose for easy debugging if OP want's to extend that to add more `KeyCodes`. You can see the `Debug.Log("Pressed" + entry.Key)` inside it. OP can use replace `keyCodeDic.ContainsKey` and everything inside it with `TryGetValue` if everything is set.